# Torsion in number field modulo rationals

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $E$ be a quadratic number field. Is there a nice description of the torsion subgroup of $E^\times/{\mathbb Q}^\times$? Is it finite? How does it change when varying the field $E$?

Comment: If $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, then the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, generated by the class of $\sqrt{d}$. Sketch of proof : 1) prove that there is no prime-to-$2$ torsion 2) identify the $2$-torsion subgroup 3) show that the $2$-primary torsion is $2$-torsion.

Comment: @js21: You probably mean $d>0$, so $E$ is real quadratic. So the imaginary fields are missing. If you are sure that it works, why don't you write down a proof below?

Comment: @Venkataramana I don't really see how $1+x\sqrt{d}$ would have finite order for arbitrary $x$.

Comment: @Corbennick: Yes, $d > 0$ in my comment (for some reason, I thought I read "real quadratic").  The answer is the same for $d \neq -1,-3$, though. And I am not going to write down a proof.

Comment: @js21: I don't think this is correct if $d$ is not a prime.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that js21's answer is correct. If you have a torsion element $[e]$ then, by checking valuations, the fractional ideal $(e)$ can only involve primes of $\Bbb Q$ and ramified primes, so wlog $(e)$ is a product of (positive powers of) ramified primes. However, if $(e)$ is a product of ramified primes then $(e)^2$ comes from an ideal of $\Bbb Q$, so $e^2$ is a root of unity times an element of $\Bbb Q$: for all $d$ this forces the ideal $(e)$ to either be trivial or equal to $(\sqrt{-d})$, and so $e = u$ or $e = u \sqrt{-d}$ for $u$ a root of unity.

Comment: @Tyler Lawson: Suppose $d$ is a product $p_1\ldots p_k$ of primes; assume for simplicity that  $E$ has  class number 1. Then $\sqrt{d}=\pi _1\ldots \pi _k$, where $\pi _i$ is a prime in $E$ with $\pi _i^2=p_i$, giving a 2-torsion element in $E^*/\mathbb{Q}^*$. It is easy to see that these elements are independent over $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: @abx The point of the squaring argument is roughly that there is always a subgroup $(\Bbb Z/2)^{k-1}$ in the class group, where $k$ is the number of ramified primes. E.g. in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{6})$, the prime $2$ is not principal because then we would have an element with $\pi^2 = \pm 2$, but this only happens when $E = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{\pm 2})$.

Comment: @Tyler Lawson: Ah, of course, thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, if $x = a + b \sqrt{d}$ is not rational, while $x^2 = a^2 + db^2 + 2ab \sqrt{d}$ is, then $2ab =0$ so $a = 0$ : this implies $x \in \mathbb{Q^{\times}} \sqrt{d}$. This takes care of step $2)$ in my first comment.